# Combining multiple columns of values together in R

Tags: r, binning

So I scripted a code that allows me to bin values in a single column. However, the problem I have is that my data is contained in multiple columns, all of varying length and with NAs in it. The script I have for binning goes like this:-

```
bin <- seq(min(data[, 1]), max(data[, 1]), by = 0.0005)
binnedData <- tapply(data[, 1], cut(data[, 1], breaks = bin), median)
```

I was wondering whether there was a way I could combine all the values from all columns into one massive long column so I can basically run this, or whether there's a way in which I can tweak this so that I can run it on my 1000 x 1000 matrix

This is taken from part of my data:-

```
102.23144 123.23242 102.23145
103.23144 123.23242 102.36563
103.83637        NA 102.36356
104.23225        NA 102.23423
105.87890        NA        NA
```

And the expected outcome with just combining column values:-

```
102.23144 
103.23144 
103.83637      
104.23225   
105.87890
123.23242
123.23242
102.23145
102.36563
102.36356
102.23423
```

And outcome with binning:-

```
(102.0000 - 102.0005) - Median of all values that fall into bin
(102.0005 - 102.0010) - Median of all values that fall into bin
(102.0015 - 102.0020) - Median of all values that fall into bin
```

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with expected output.  It is not clear whether the `binning` would be the similar for multiple column in your dataset. i.e. does the `by=.00005` varies?

Comment: May be you need `unlist` i.e. `data1 <- data.frame(V1=unname(na.omit(unlist(data)))); bin <- seq(min(data1[,1]), max(data1[,1]), by=0.0005);binnedData <- tapply(data1[, 1], cut(data1[, 1], breaks = bin), median)`

Comment: Just added now, apologies! And the bin 0.0005 would remain constant across all columns. Basically I want the values from all columns to be binned into 0.0005 group, with the median taken of all the values that fall within the bins

Comment: Based on your code on `bin` and `binnedData`, I get a lot of NAs for binnedData

Comment: Yeah the NAs are expected as not all bins will contain values, but I intend in removing those bins that don't have values in them after

Comment: Okay, have you tried the modified code I commented

Comment: When I apply the first line of coding (the unlist part) I get the following:

`> data1 <- data.frame(V1=unname(na.omit(unlist(serum_neg_data))));
> head(data1)`

`[1] V1.1    V1.2    V1.3    V1.4    V1.5    V1.6    V1.7    V1.8    V1.9    V1.10   V1.11   V1.12   V1.13   V1.14   V1.15  
  [16] V1.16   V1.17   V1.18   V1.19   V1.20   V1.21   V1.22   V1.23 `

Comment: Do you have a `matrix` or `data.frame`?  I thought you had a `data.frame`.  If you have a `matrix`, then `data1 <- data.frame(V1=na.omit(c(as.matrix(data))))`

Comment: Yeah it says it was a data frame when i do is.data.frame, but I've managed to get it sorted now but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using melt function from reshape2 package.

Here is some of your test data:

```
test <- data.frame(V1=c(102.2314,103.2314,103.8364,104.2322,105.8789),
                   V2=c(123.2324,123.2324,NA,NA,NA),
                   V3=c(102.2314,102.3656,102.3636,102.2342,NA)
                  )

> test
        V1       V2       V3
1 102.2314 123.2324 102.2314
2 103.2314 123.2324 102.3656
3 103.8364       NA 102.3636
4 104.2322       NA 102.2342
5 105.8789       NA       NA
```

and then use melt function -

```
test_m <- melt(test)
```

But there are NAs.

```
> test_m
   variable    value
1        V1 102.2314
2        V1 103.2314
3        V1 103.8364
4        V1 104.2322
5        V1 105.8789
6        V2 123.2324
7        V2 123.2324
8        V2       NA
9        V2       NA
10       V2       NA
11       V3 102.2314
12       V3 102.3656
13       V3 102.3636
14       V3 102.2342
15       V3       NA
```

So, now same step with this filter -

```
test_m<- melt(test)[which(!(is.na(melt(test)[,2]))),]

> test_m
   variable    value
1        V1 102.2314
2        V1 103.2314
3        V1 103.8364
4        V1 104.2322
5        V1 105.8789
6        V2 123.2324
7        V2 123.2324
11       V3 102.2314
12       V3 102.3656
13       V3 102.3636
14       V3 102.2342
```

So, NAs removed. You can select only the 2nd col of the data remove the variable name col.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `data.frame`, this could be done with `stack` from `base R`

```
na.omit(stack(test))[,1,drop=FALSE]
#    values
#1  102.2314
#2  103.2314
#3  103.8364
#4  104.2322
#5  105.8789
#6  123.2324
#7  123.2324
#11 102.2314
#12 102.3656
#13 102.3636
#14 102.2342
```

Or

```
data.frame(V1= unname(na.omit(unlist(test))))
```

#### data

```
test <- structure(list(V1 = c(102.2314, 103.2314, 103.8364, 104.2322, 
105.8789), V2 = c(123.2324, 123.2324, NA, NA, NA), V3 = c(102.2314, 
102.3656, 102.3636, 102.2342, NA)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
```